# Pandas dataframe column with mixed types (float, int, string) - how to convert float to int?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column that contains various data types (int, str, float), many of these values should be int but were imported as float (5.0 rather than 5).  Looking for any suggestions on how to quickly identify and update these records without impacting the rest of the rows.

My current solution works, but it's having to iterate over millions of rows and taking a very long time - there must be an easier way.

Current approach (very slow)

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    thisKey = row['key']
    thisValue = row['value']
    if (type(thisValue) == float):
        df.at[index, 'value'] = int(thisValue)
```

Should I consider hitting it with a .loc to pull out all the records that are float and then convert the entire column of the new (only float) df in a single pass?  Can you do a .loc against the data type of a specific cell to build the df I need?  Can I do the inverse to get all the non-float for the .concat I would need to do after the INT update?

Comment: Why not to use [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)?

Comment: Something like  `df['value'] = df['value'].astype(int, errors='ignore')`?

Comment: I just tried `df.astype({'value': 'int'})` but it's failing due to the mixed types in the column, is there something I can add to make this a viable option?  I do have a key:value pair that I need to keep in float format, is there any way to skip this keypair.

Comment: `df.astype({'value': 'int'}, errors='ignore')`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
make minimal example to solve problem

Comment: @rickhg12hs - Thank you, this is exactly what I needed, this step now runs in two seconds!

Answer (score 1):

@rickhg12hs provided the best approach for this problem.  I was able to update the column in the dataframe using a single line rather than the very inefficient FOR loop I started with.

```
   df = df.astype({'value': 'int'}, errors='ignore')
```

This single line processes my DF with 27M rows in under 2 seconds while the FOR loop was taking over 30 minutes!  The errors='ignore' allowed me to process over String and valid Float objects, exactly as I needed.